# Storyboard Interface Not Updating Straight Away

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, healthkit

So, I though I was finally getting the hang of iOS development and then I encounter this....

So I am trying to create a health app that uses health kit to import some of the users data and then process it in various ways and so on.

Upon performing the initial import I run through each data point to analyse data on it. During this time which is about 7 seconds I have a UI progress bar that is supposed to update and finish as the data processing does. When the processing is finished, I also have some UILabels that should update.

None of the UI elements I add update until what seems to be a long (>5 seconds) and random (as much as 60 seconds) after the processing has finished.

I know from NSLog statements that the processing is completing correctly and that the variables that that should update the progress bar and the labels are correct.

The phone does experience high CPU load during that processing time so I wonder if that might be linked.

After accessing heart rate data in the viewdidload method, the readHeartRateData method is called, its then processes separately like the following:

```
-(void)readHeartRateData {
    NSLog(@"Read Heart Rate Data");
    HKQuantityType *heartRate = [HKObjectType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate];
    NSSortDescriptor *timeSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:HKSampleSortIdentifierEndDate ascending:NO];

    // construct the query & since we are not filtering the data the predicate is set to nil
    HKSampleQuery *query = [[HKSampleQuery alloc] initWithSampleType:heartRate predicate:nil limit:1000000 sortDescriptors:@[timeSortDescriptor] resultsHandler:^(HKSampleQuery *query, NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
        NSInteger dataPoints = results.count;
        self.data1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Total Data Points Collected: %lu", dataPoints];//Does not update straight away

        for (int i=0; i<dataPoints; i++) { // The 'processing' bit
            float value1 = (unsigned long)dataPoints;
            float progress = (i/value1);
            [self.progressView setProgress:progress animated:YES];// No update until after process finished
            HKQuantitySample *quantitySample = [results objectAtIndex:i];
            NSDate *date = quantitySample.startDate;
            NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
            timeFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH";
            NSString *dateString = [timeFormatter stringFromDate: date];
            int check = [dateString intValue];

            if(check > 0 && check < 8){         
                nightCount = nightCount + 1;            
                HKUnit *beatsPerMinute = [[HKUnit countUnit] unitDividedByUnit:[HKUnit minuteUnit]];            
                HKQuantity *data = quantitySample.quantity;            
                double dataValue = [data doubleValueForUnit:beatsPerMinute];            
                nightTotal = nightTotal + dataValue;
            }
        }
        NSLog(@"Number of Night Data Points: %li", (long)nightCount);
        nightAverageRate = nightTotal/nightCount;
        NSLog(@"Average Night Heart Rate: %li",(long)nightAverageRate);
        self.data4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Total Night-time Data Points: %lu", (long)nightCount];
        self.data5.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Average Night-time BPM: %li", (long)nightAverageRate];        
        // if there is a data point, dispatch to the main queue
        if (results) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
               // NSDate *startDate, *endDate;

            });
        }
    }];

    // do not forget to execute the query after its constructed
    [healthStore executeQuery:query];
}
```

Any suggestions on why there is this random delay after the data processing is finished before it updates the UI labels and progress view? CPU usage is high at the start but drops as soon as the processing is finished.
Many thanks for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HKSampleQuery executes on a background thread and its resultsHandler also executes on a background thread.

From the documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKSampleQuery_Class/index.html)

> This method runs the query on an anonymous background queue. When the query is complete, it executes the results handler on the background queue. Typically, you dispatch these results back to the main queue to update your user interface

You're heading along the right lines with the dispatch_async block, but you need to put all the changes to your UI in that block

The reason for the random delay is the UI won't redraw until something else triggers a UI update. I'd put money on the redraw happening when you tap the screen.

Comment: Thats great, is there a method to call the screen redraw?

Comment: Yes, but that's not the way to solve your problem. You must always update the UI from the main queue.